# Edit Template File from Table Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a template excel file stored in an s3 Bucket that I am downloading which more or less matches the layout column by column of a table I have inside my web application. Basically what I want to do is take some information that is in the web table and write it into the template file on download.

I am downloading from the s3 bucket like so, which is generates a URL to be downloaded from

```js
Export()
  {
    console.log("This function is running")
    const myKey = '...key'
    const mySecret = '...secret'
    AWS.config.update
    ({
      accessKeyId: myKey,
      secretAccessKey: mySecret
    });
    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const myBucket = 'bucket'
    const bucketKey = 'bucket key'
    const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5

    let url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Bucket: myBucket,
      Key: bucketKey,
      Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
    })

    console.log("The URL is " + url)

    function downloadDataUrl(url)
    {
      let link = document.createElement('a')
      link.download = 'downloadFileName'
      link.href = url
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click();
    }

    downloadDataUrl(url)
  }
```

Now the table I have in my webpage has basically the same columns what I hope to do, if possible is when the download button is clicked not only is the template file downloaded but the data that's in the table on the webpage is also added into the relevant cells in this case the template file is an excel. I am not sure however, if this sort of data transfer needs to occur on the S3 side of things or if I do it within my angular program or both.

Comment: 1. Putting a secret key on your front end to generate a signed url is pointless. Might as well just make the bucket public read and not take the risk of exposing an IAM key. 2. You can’t read or modify an excel file in front end JavaScript trivially. Store it as a csv instead and you can use any number of utilities to read and populate your data. If you need an excel file you’ll likely have to add a server element in somewhere

Comment: Unfortunately everything needs to be saved as excel for data validation purposes

Comment: and yes I plan on refactoring all the URL stuff but the main priority now is completing the task I described above and then I'll go back and kind of redo stuff

Comment: 3. If you want to modify a file prior to download, you’ll need to read it as a blob via Ajax first, modify it, then simulate the download.

Comment: ^if you could put this as an answer with maybe an example code snippet that would be extremely helpful I appreciate your insight very much on all this

Comment: Like i said, if you need excel, you need a server component to do this for you. You won’t be able to pull it off easily with front end JavaScript. Not sure if it’s possible at all tbh.

Comment: there's a library for it but it's very buggy atm and I'm hesitant to use it for something that'll be used for the company im working with just because I think it'll create more problems than it solves

Comment: Then what you do is create a server endpoint (api gateway / lambda maybe?) that accepts a post of your json data from your front end table, grabs the template, generates the excel file, stores it in s3, and then returns a signed url of where you can download the data, then you simulate the download as you have with the signed url.